# Why children are null ? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a small code of javaFX.
I want to draw in canvas but I have some problem of beginner I really don't understand well javaFX.

This is my `Main.java`

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
Controller controller;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        controller= new Controller();
        controller.Pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        System.out.printf("kk"+controller.canvas.isResizable());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(controller.Pane, controller.Pane.getPrefWidth(), controller.Pane.getPrefHeight()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

this is sample.FXML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="Pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="284.0" prefWidth="484.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Canvas fx:id="canvas"  height="267.0" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="9.0" width="459.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="13.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="9.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

For `the controller.java` there is only canvas and pane declaration.

My question :

1. Pane is the parent and canvas is the children after doing FXMLloader.load etc, pane is not null but the children are null in the method start (outside like an event of button the children aren't null) why is children null?
   [image]
2. To make the canvas resizable there is no method to do such thing, the only solution is to extends from `Canvas` and `@Override` method `isResizable` make it `true`. But `Canvas` I get it from FXML if I do 
   `Canvas MyCanvas= new CanvasResizable();`
   this dosen't work I don't know why.
   is there a way like android to make for example `canvas=(Canvas) findbyid(FXML.id.canvas);` (something similar)

and my last question how can we change the color of canvas there is no method to do that.

I'm sorry if my question is already asked by a diffirent why, I searched so much in google there is a lack of documentation of javaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FXML controller should not be created directly. It will be initialized for you by `FXMLLoader`:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Pane root = loader.load(); // controller was initialized
        controller = loader.getController();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, root.getPrefWidth(), root.getPrefHeight()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can find more details in Oracle tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm#CACFEHBI